# How can I determine the number of arithmetic operations per second of a processor?

Tags: hardware, execution-time

What is the best way to determine how many additions, multiplications, exponentiations etc does a processor perform per second according to its specifications (frequency, memory type etc)? E.g. an Intel i7? The goal is to estimate the performance of a program/service before choosing on what machine it is deployed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost impossible these days.

Modern processors have many tricks up their sleeve; for example, branch prediction, which gives very different results for different implementations (see the popular [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) question).

I think your best bet is checking benchmarks (e.g., http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html), as these provide the 'overall' picture you're looking for.

Comment: And how can I make an estimation for the i7 processors from benchmarking? In my code, I count instructions and their types, I do not know how many cycles is each one of them.

Comment: Compare the benchmarks of your system to the i7. But again, I deem it close to impossible to determine exactly how well your program will run - why exactly do you need such an exact estimation?